# How to generate the default CREATE TABLE statement based on the connected data source in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to be able to generate the default CREATE TABLE statement based on the connected data source in SSIS, using a variable as the table name.

How do I do that?

I read this answer: [Dynamic table create and load data in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738805/dynamic-table-create-and-load-data-in-ssis)

However, I want to be able to dynamically create step "2)2. Add SQL Task in container (to create table if it is not present)"

Please provide your answer relevant to SSIS 2017, as some functionality has changed from older versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a single step.

What you could do is use a first ExecuteSQL Task to query the source connection and query the meta-tables or views to build a CREATE TABLE statement and store it in an SSIS Variable.

Then you can use a second ExecuteSQL Task to execute the statement in your variable on the Destination connection.